# My onClick function is not working, and the menu is not showing

Tags: reactjs

```
function Navigation() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState('false');
  return (
    <div>
      <nav>
        <div className="siteName">Site Name</div>
        <ul
          className="navLinks"
          style={{transform: open ? 'translateX (0px)' : ''}}
        >
          <li>
            <a href="/">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="experience">Experience</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <i onClick={() => setOpen(!open)} className="fa-solid fa-bars burger" />
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have the onClick function in the hamburger menu and set state. But when I was trying out the button, it is not working, and the menu is not showing up.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a `string` containing the word "false" to the `useState` hook.
In-order to pass a `boolean` value, you need to remove the quotation marks.

**Example:**

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But it is still not working, and the menu bar is not showing still

Comment: Well, it should fix the matter of the state-change. You can verify this by logging the value of state in a `useEffect` hook. As for why the menu is not showing, it depends on your structure and whatever else you have going in your code.

Comment: However, I would generally suggest to use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator) in cases like these. Instead of hiding the menu out of bounds with `translateX`.

Comment: Also, just as a general advice. Avoid recommendations for installing third-party libraries for simple things that can be easily achieved without them.

Answer (score -1):

You made `boolean` value `string` inside `useState`

```bash
const [open, setOpen] = useState('false'); <--here
```

Since if `string` has value it is considered to be `true`.

### Recommendation

I recommend you to install library `clsx` for conditionally render CSS in React.

**Navgation.js**

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";

export default function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <nav>
        <div className="siteName">Site Name</div>
        <ul className={clsx("navlinks", open ? "openStyle" : "closeStyle")}>
          <li>
            <a href="/">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="experience">Experience</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <button onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>OPEN</button>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And add stylings for you opening and closing menu. Inside CSS file add this

**style.css**

```css
.openStyle {
  color: red;
}

.closeStyle {
  color: black;
}
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-pond-v50qcv)

***Useful link:***

[3 Ways Conditionally Render CSS in React](https://dev.to/jasurkurbanov/3-ways-conditionally-render-css-in-react-1j5i)